# What is the purpose of Package Relationships in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, package, relationship

What exactly is a Package Relationship (ZipPackage) in .NET? I know what a Package is but I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of relationships. Could you give examples of when I would want to use them and what they are good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx) (Package Class):

> Package is an abstract class that can be used to organize objects into a single entity of a defined physical format for portability and efficient access.

And:

> A PackageRelationship ("relationship") defines an association between a source Package or PackagePart and a target object. A PackageRelationship can be one of two types, each of which can be one of two forms:

```
* A package-level relationship (created by the Package.CreateRelationship method) relates a Package to either:
      o A target part in the package.
      o A target resource outside the package.
* A part-level relationship (created by the PackagePart.CreateRelationship method) relates a source PackagePart to either:
      o Another target part in the package.
      o A target resource outside the package.
```

So, when creating a `Package`, if you want to indicate that there is a relationship between an object to another part of the package, you should use a `PackageRelationship` to indicate what kind of relationship it is.

A `ZipPackage` can also be used to work with Open Office XML files - in this use case, it is sometime useful to indicate relationships of objects to each other. See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/office-open-xml-i-exploring-the-office-open-xml-formats-RZ010243529.aspx?section=15).

Comment: Yes I can google too... But what does it mean? What should I use it for?

Comment: @Andreas Zita - When working with Open Office XML files, to indicate relationships within the document parts.

Comment: I still dont get it. Is it only a logical representation of some kind of connection between two resources I can interpret in any way I like? "It is sometimes useful" -> Why is it useful?

Comment: @Andreas Zita - Yes, a logical relationship. Useful For example for a Table of Context, an Index, a grouping of Clip Art objects.

Comment: Office document level addins (binary files) can be stored in a package along with the actual document and Custom XML parts.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is to connect things together so that they are deployed, and more importantly un-deployed at the same time.

Say for example you have a program and you have a package of GIFs that it uses. Then you want the GIFs to be available when your program is installed, and you want them to be cleaned up when the program is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion good examples are all [file formats using OPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions)

And an example in c# for an opc container with an preview image would be implemented f.e.:

```
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO.Packaging;

using (var package = Package.Open( your_Zip/OPC_File_Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
    // Add the Preview Image to the OPC container
    var imagePart = package.CreatePart( PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri("preview.png", UriKind.Relative)), "image/png");
    package.CreateRelationship( imagePart.Uri, TargetMode.Internal, OpcConstants.RelationshipTypes.PREVIEWIMAGE, "preview");

    using(var imageStream = imagePart.GetStream( FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write ))
    {
        imageStream.Write( your_preview_Image_Byte_array, 0, your_preview_Image_Byte_array.Length);
    }
}


   private byte[] GetPreviewImage(System.IO.Packaging.Package package)
   {
        if (!package.RelationshipExists("preview"))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var previewRel = package.GetRelationship("preview");
        var previewUri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(previewRel.TargetUri);

        var previewImagePart = package.GetPart(previewUri);
        using (var previewImageStream = previewImagePart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            previewImageStream.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

And to convert your png to an byte array you could do [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv)

So the benefit would be, you could afterwards use your defined Relationship-Id (="preview") to access your previewImage in an opc container